# Как объявить делегированную функцию в структуре?

Tags: c#, struct

При сборке следующего кода возникает ошибка:

```
delegate void Func();
Func f1; // <- Тут всё в порядке
Dictionary<string, Func> f2; // <- Так тоже можно

public struct CSProtocols
{
    public string Protocol;
    Func f3; // <- А вот ут возникает ошибка: "Поле ... должно быть полностью определено до возврата управления в вызывающий метод"

    public CSProtocols(string _Protocol)
    {

        Protocol = _Protocol;
    }
}
```

Неужели нельзя объявить делегированные мтоды в структуре? 
Если нет, как бы вы посоветовали решить подобную задачку, когда нужна структура с несколькими полями и ссылкой на метод? Вариант с Dictionary не подходит из-за ограничения на количество атрибутов (всего 2).

Visual Studio 2015 Community, если вдруг это имеет значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так инициируйте ваш делегат в конструкторе. Например так:

```
public CSProtocols(string _Protocol)
{
    f3 = null;
    Protocol = _Protocol;
}
```

либо с использованием конструктора по умолчанию:

```
public CSProtocols(string _Protocol) : this()
{    
    Protocol = _Protocol;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! В голову не пришло, что делегат требует отдельной инициализации.